# Getting gap in HTML 5 progress element

Tags: html, css, progress

I have style HTML 5 progress tag. And removed default styles however I am not sure why there is small gap coming in between border and filled area in progress. Please see below screenshot.

Please help me to remove 1px gap between filled dark blue area and red border.

[image]

Stackblitz URL: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qgwxn1?

Comment: Did you try zooming your screen in and out ? Does it affect the behaviour ?

Comment: The gap is not there in all browsers at all zoom levels. It looks more like an edge effect which can occur when the system tries to map part CSS pixels to screen pixels ( there may be several screen pixels to one CSS pixel) than a bug in the CSS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use height 100% to fill the gap, and border to box-shadow method to completely remove any remaining spaces,

```
progress[value] {
  flex-grow: 1;
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
  /* Reset the default appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 5px;
  overflow: hidden;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px red;
  /* border: 1px solid red; */
}
```